# How do I autoplay a video after clicking on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using the below code in a WordPress editor. With my current code when I click on the image the actual video shows up, and I have to click the video again to play it.

I want to change it so that an image of the video is displayed and when I click on that the video should start to play. I just have to click once. Right now I have to click twice which is bad user experience. This is required to reduce page load time.

```
<div class="youtube" id="PpMS2SP_3Fs" style="width:100%; height: 600px;"></div>
<script>
  var videos = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube");

  for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    var youtube = videos[i];
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "https://www.sociosquares.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/vid-img1-opti.jpg");
    img.setAttribute("class", "thumb");

    var circle = document.createElement("div");
    circle.setAttribute("class", "circle");

    youtube.appendChild(img);
    youtube.appendChild(circle);

    youtube.onclick = function() {
      var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.id + "?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=PpMS2SP_3Fs");
      //"https://www.youtube.com/embed/PpMS2SP_3Fs?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=PpMS2SP_3Fs");

      iframe.style.width = this.style.width;
      iframe.style.height = this.style.height;

      this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
    };
  }
</script>
```

I expected the video to autoplay after a click on the image, but it doesn't, and I have to click again to play the video.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#image_id').click(function() {
  jQuery(".youtube").attr('src', jQuery(".youtube", parent).attr('src') + '?autoplay=1'); 
});
```

`image_id` is your image element id you are clicking and `youtube` is the class of the  iframe your embed has.